# Lint displays warning for auto-generated files even though they are excluded in tslint.json

Tags: angular, swagger, lint, tslint

In this Angular project we include auto-generated models from a swagger definition.

The generated files does not satisfy `tslint` and will therefore display a warning. Therefore we choose to exclude the files:

```
"linterOptions": {
    "exclude": ["*.json", "src/**/*.json", "../PathToModels/**/*.ts"]
}
```

However the `linter` still displays warnings for all the models.
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the exclusion rule from the `angular.json` file.

```
"lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": ["src/tsconfig.app.json", "src/tsconfig.spec.json"],
        "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "../PathToModels/**/*.ts"]
      }
    }
```